# Sketch the region described by $\text{Im}\left[\frac{z-z_{1}}{z-z_{2}}\right] =0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923685/find-loci-of-the-points-in-complex-plane-such-that-mathrmim-fracz-z-1z-z?rq=1) is similar, but please do not mark this as a duplicate, because it is not exactly the same as what is being asked in that question, and besides, the answers given to it do not answer my question.

I need to sketch the region described by $\text{Im}\left[\frac{z-z_{1}}{z-z_{2}}\right]=0$.

To that effect, I multiplied top and bottom by the complex conjugate $\overline{z}-\overline{z_{2}}$ in a manner similar to that found [in this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502492/geometric-interpretation-of-re-fracz-z-1z-z-2-0?rq=1) to obtain that $\text{Im}\left[\frac{z-z_{1}}{z-z_{2}}\right] = 0$ is equivalent to $\text{Im}\left[\frac{(z-z_{1})(\overline{z}-\overline{z_{2}})}{|z-z_{2}|^{2}}\right] = 0$.

Then, this is really the same as $\text{Im}[(z-z_{1})(\overline{z}-\overline{z_{2}})] = 0$, or $(x-x_{2})(y-y_{1})-(x-x_{1})(y-y_{2})=0$, which is the imaginary part of $(z-z_{1})(\overline{z}-\overline{z_{2}})$ when you multiply it out.

Now, I'm thinking this is a line, and so I tried to rewrite it in a more "liney" form: $$y = x \frac{(y_{1}-y_{2})}{(x_{1}-x_{2})} + \frac{x_{1}y_{2} - x_{2}y_{1}}{x_{1} - x_{2}}$$

So, it's a line with slope $\displaystyle\frac{y_{1}-y_{2}}{x_{1}-x_{2}}$ and $y-$intercept $\displaystyle\left(0, \frac{x_{1}y_{2} - x_{2}y_{1}}{x_{1} - x_{2}}\right)$.

**But, how do I draw this?**

Comment: are you trying to solve $im(\ldots) = 0$ or $im(\ldots) = z$ ?

Comment: @mercio, $im(\cdots) = 0$. I fixed my typos above, so it should be clearer now. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation $y = x\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} + \frac{x_2y_1-x_1y_2}{x_2-x_1}$ is simply the equation of a line joining two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so given two complex numbers, $z_1$ and $z_2$, the region you described is the line joining those two points.

Edit: Oh, the line doesn't include $z_2$. I forgot about that. So the line in the picture should have a hole at $z_2$.
[image]

Comment: you drew a picture and everything! Thank you!